# Find and replace string with placeholders in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

Is it possible to search for a string like this:

```
http://getfile1.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-03-30/kBpHaviyoumcvCEHnGnrDfwHwmJIrnqrHrxhCnHwfBIHuDsxbemHlxwEwCdi/IMG_6870.jpg
```

while some parts are placeholders like:

```
http://getfile%.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-03-%/%/IMG_6870.jpg
```

and replace it with:

```
http://my.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/IMG_6870.jpg
```

Thank you for inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL support for regular expressions is very limited, but you can try with a combination of SUBSTRING_INDEX and REPLACE string functions, like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET
  url =
  CONCAT(
    'http://my.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/',
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -3),
          '-',
          3),
        'temp-',
        ''),
      '-',
      '/'),
    '/',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1));
```

But you need to make sure that all strings have the same format. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a622a/1).

Comment: wow that looks promising! How do i have to use the update if the urls are in a text field with other stuff around and maybe containing more then one of these urls? like ``some text here http://getfile1.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-03-30/kBpHaviyoumcvCEHnGnrDfwHwmJIrnqrHrxhCnHwfBIHuDsxbemHlxwEwCdi/IMG_6870.jpg and one other here http://getfile2.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-04-28/asdfasfdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf/IMG_6870.jpg and finishing text`` thank you very very much!

Comment: if there are multiple urls in the same field, i don't think there's an easy way obtain what you need... but if urls always begin with `http://` and end with `.jpg` and there's no other http:// and .jpg in the string... maybe we can still extract the url... but do you need to keep the text around your url?

Comment: yes, because this kind of urls are in a "content" field of blog posts. but maybe i have to export all data into an XML file, and replace it in there (with some fancy regex) and upload it again...

Comment: As mentioned I did it with a python script, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/sspross/9200228). I mark this question as solved, because fthiella's answer fits my question as it is written above.