# Remove text with random string

Tags: mysql

I need to remove one `tr` line, with 2x `td` - 1x "Product code", second random value.

Tried with this query:

```
$vendorrefenrceremovefi =  mysql_query("
UPDATE ps_product_lang 
SET description = REPLACE
(description,  '<tr><td>Product code</td><td>C%</td></tr><tr class=\"info\" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number',  
'<tr class=\"info\" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number' );
"  ,$db) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

But it doesn't work.

The original code:

```
<tr><td>Product code</td><td>CXXX</td></tr><tr class="info" bgcolor=#F3F3F3><td>Original Part Number</td><td>
```

The `xx` can be a random value.

Comment: "But the doesn't work." - what does that mean? Do you get an error? Which? Does the query crash? How? Does nothing happen at all? Does the universe implode?

Comment: nothing happen at all

Comment: Replace does not work this way. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/986870/1786423 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21998359/1786423 for alternatives.